# how to replace the inner springs of a cardboard sleeve CD case?

Tags: cd, media

the plastic springs in the center of CD cases can break, and when a couple of them are gone, the CD will fall out of place. regular jewel boxes have a removable tray which can be replaced; cardboard CD sleeves have the plastic glued in place. what product is used by music librarians to repair such cases - possibly a rather dense foam cylinder cut to length?

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but I've found in an office supplies shop a packet of round self adhesive foam tabs. These are used to mail CDs or archive them in    cardboard or something, but they can be used as a hack to recover an irreplaceable package.

Comment: @joseem, that sounds great. i would like to find this product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a search on the web and found [this product](http://www.cd-spider.com/cd-dvd-spider-foam-button-holder-hub) which is the kind of product that I mentioned in my comment above:

[image]

But the same search also returned [this one](http://www.shop4tech.com/item5658.html) which is probably exactly what you're looking for:

[image]

Now I'm not recommending these specific products and suppliers (I don't know them and I don't even know if they're available in your region) but by searching for these type of products you may find what you're looking for from a merchant that servers your area).

Comment: this helped me to find the products. the black "spider" won't fit as long as part of the old spider is still in place, but the foam "dots" or "hubs" will. thank you, i am ordering some.

Comment: "Memorex CD & DVD Hubs" is a product that worked for me. the hubs have a wide base to glue down which is clear but matte and necessarily sits on top of an area of the old, broken base plate. the CD sits about 1mm higher than it used to.